# Render dynamic HTML as a value attribute to TextArea field in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, innerhtml

I have a simple textarea tag.

```
<textarea value={this.state.currentValue} disabled={this.props.readOnly}/>
```

I am trying to use **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** but not sure how to set correctly inside value attribute of TextArea tag. I know and used **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** which works fine when used with div, body tags.

```
 renderHtml: function(){
        return (
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html : this.state.currentValue}} 
        );
    }
   <TextArea value={this.renderHtml()} disabled={this.props.readOnly}/>
```

Comment: Are you trying to have the textarea render the HTML? Or simply have it display the code. In other words, if the html is something like this `<span>hello world</span>` do you want to see only hello world, or the actual markup?

Comment: I want to have textarea tag render the HTML. Its value comes from REST api. So I want to see the actual markup.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for any HTML element, only Strings are allowed as value. Solution for this is to use rich text WYSIWYG editors.